# How to show view in canvas

Tags: android, view, canvas

I try to create my own view and try to add  buttons or TextViews in it.

```
public class Test extends View{
Button _button;

public Test(Context context) {
    super(context);
    _button = new Button(getContext());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), 100, 100, new Paint());
}
```

}

So how to show this button in canvas like this Bitmap?

Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this problem?